# How to remove duplicate vertices from a mesh?

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh, vertex, assimp

I am using assimp to import a mesh created using blender.

Here is the code for that:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;

// And have it read the given file with some example postprocessing
// Usually - if speed is not the most important aspect for you - you'll
// probably to request more postprocessing than we do in this example.
const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path,
    aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace |
    aiProcess_Triangulate |
    aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
    aiProcess_SortByPType);
```

Now this works find but the problem comes when i try to deform the mesh by making small changes in vertex positions of the mesh like.

```
verts[i].position += verts[i].normal * noise(verts[i].position);
```

The problem is that the common points un triangles are made of separate vertices thus the mesh breaks up like:

[image]

What can i do so that there are no duplicate vertices

Comment: I believe you can use the MeshLab to convert it to a manifold mesh, but I am not expert in MeshLab

Comment: Thanks! It isworking! But is there a way to do it programatically? And how complex would that be?